# Powershell replace issue

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

Having troubles in PowerShell writing the regex to replace the following multiple occurrences of the below inside a file. They are the only characters on those lines

```
]

[
```

I want to replace both brackets with a comma

before:

```
]

[
```

after:

```
,
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: i THINK this will do the job - `-replace '(?sm)\].+\[', ','`. the `(?sm)` sets regex flags - single line and multi line.

Comment: So what is your issue and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a RegEx see your input from file as a single string you need to either use `Get-Content` with the [-raw parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-3.0) (PSv3+)
-or-

use -join to concatenate the array of strings to a single string.

Using your whole question text stored in file sample.txt:

```
> (Get-Content .\sample.txt -raw) -replace '\][\r\n]+\[',','


Having troubles in PowerShell writing the regex to replace the following multiple occurrences of the below inside a file. They are the only characters on those lines

,

I want to replace both brackets with a comma

before:

,

after:

,

Any suggestions?
```

Comment: Thanks @LotPings using the -raw and the regex provided did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using MS Windows, in which (and MS-DOS) new line is marked with subsequent *Carriage Return* (`\r`) and *Line Feed* (`\n`) characters, which you have to match twice, because of the empty line.

As brackets are special characters in regular expressions, you have to escape them with `\` and also include `m` modifier for multi line match:

```
$s -replace "(?m)\[\r\n\r\n\]", ","
```